# Get Ticks per second and convert to String value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, timespan

How do I get number of ticks per second of DateTime.UtcNow and convert it to a String value?

BAD QUESTION: try again [Get ten millionths of a second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123894/get-ten-millionths-of-a-second)

Comment: var stringValue = "10000000";

Comment: BAD QUESTION: try again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123894/get-ten-millionths-of-a-second :(

Comment: Don't repost the same question, add information instead.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A particular *value* of `DateTime` doesn't have a "ticks per second" associated with it; ticks are ticks no matter which `DateTime` they're in. Ticks are 100 nanoseconds long, so there are 10,000,000 of them per second.

Now to get that as a string is as simple as the string literal "10000000"... although in general you would obtain a number and just call `ToString()` on it. For instance, you could use:

```
string ticksPerSecond = TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond.ToString();
```

Your question is a slightly odd one, so I wonder whether we're missing something... could you edit the question with more details about what you're trying to do. For example, are you trying to determine the number of ticks *within the particular second* of a particular `DateTime`? That's most easily done as:

```
long ticks = dt.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you may want [`TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.tickspersecond.aspx).

```
Console.WriteLine("tps = {0}", TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

You find the ticks per second as a constant on TimeSpan:

```
TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond
```

Not sure what you are trying to do though...

```
(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond).ToString() // Total number of seconds...
```

Answer (score 2):

The number of ticks per second in a DateTime value is always 10000000. One tick is 100 nanoseconds.

So, if you want to convert that to a string:

```
10000000.ToString()
```

Comment: @simendsjo: Yes, I just wanted to point out that the value never changes. You should avoid using the value altogether, if you want a ticks value as seconds, create a DateTime or TimeSpan value from it and use it's methods to get it as seconds.