# Get ten millionths of a second

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, timespan

How do I get the string value of the ten millionths of a second?
"fffffff"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Ticks per second and convert to String value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123802/get-ticks-per-second-and-convert-to-string-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

myDateTime.ToString("fffffff") should work. Is that giving some sort of error?

Also, this is from the page you linked

> Although it is possible to display the
>   ten millionths of a second component
>   of a time value, that value may not be
>   meaningful. The precision of date and
>   time values depends on the resolution
>   of the system clock. On the Windows NT
>   3.5 (and later) and Windows Vista operating systems, the clock's
>   resolution is approximately 10-15
>   milliseconds.

Comment: @Khou - It works here: `DateTime.Now.ToString("fffffff")`, what error are you getting?

Comment: Didn't need it to be meaningful, just need a counter to count up using time. Need at least 7 to 8 digits, so 00000001 to 99999999.

Comment: Getting "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'string'"

Comment: @Khou: Then you're not using the code shown. Please edit your question with the code you're actually using.

Comment: @Khou - It sounds like [`Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) is more appropriate here.

Comment: @Jon, sorry you are right, my fault, i checked again and it works!